# how to grep logs related to a particular database from mysql-general.log file?

Tags: mysql, grep

I need to filter the logs related to a specific database from a general query log file,how   can I use grep for this or Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The general query log does not record the current database when you run a query. The information is simply not in the log. The only possibility is if tables are qualified by schema name in the queries, and you can parse that out.

The slow query log *does* record the default database for each query. And you can `set global long_query_time=0` to make the slow query log record information for all queries, just like the general log.

To filter out log entries for a specific current database, I'd use pt-query-digest, which is free and part of the [Percona Toolkit](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-toolkit).

For example, here's a command that reads the slow query log, filters for entries where the current database was "test" and outputs in the format of a new slow query log.

```
pt-query-digest --filter '$event->{db} eq "test"' mysql-slow.log --no-report --output slowlog
```

However, you should be aware that this can only filter for queries that were run when the *default database* was "test". Any query can access tables in other databases, by qualifying the table name with the schema name, e.g. `SELECT * FROM mydb.mytable`. But the slow log might still record a different default database.